# mysql error 1045 (28000) no root password

Tags: mysql

I have no root password. I am only working locally and learning. I logged out to learn to try and backup a database, and now I have problems with logging in.

```
mysql -u root -p;
```

Now that gives me this error:

> Warning: Using password on the command line interface can be insecure. Error 1045 (28000) access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

So I try this:

```
mysql -u root;
```

It logs me in with no errors, but I cant see the databases I created because I'm not root even though I'm using 'root' in the command. I know I have no password because PHP logs in without one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you put `mysql -uroot -p;` command then your password is `;` for root@localhost user is incorrect, thats why its showing error.
 when you log in `mysql -u root` or simply `mysql` then it log into mysql prompt with anonymous user which is created by default when you installed mysql.

So you should run the command

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

then enter the password. if your password is not set or nothing then press enter.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason you have "mysql -uroot -p" instead of "mysql -u root -p" ?

Comment: -uroot and -u root both works, space is not matter for user name but for password it should be without space like -ppassword. @Zapp